# How to show a yes/no icon in changelist page with own colum

Tags: django, django-admin

I am writing a admin for a model .There is a column named `modbus_address_mapping_valid`,it is not the member of this model.There is only two result.How does it show the yes/no icon in page

```
def modbus_address_mapping_valid(self,obj):
    try:
        mapping_valid = models.ModbusAddressMapping.objects.filter(object_id=obj.id)[0].valid
    except Exception:
        mapping_valid = False
    if mapping_valid:
        return u'<img src="/static/admin/img/icon-no.gif" alt="False">'
    else:
        return u'<img src="/static/admin/img/icon-no.gif" alt="False">'
modbus_address_mapping_valid.short_description = 'Modbus_mapping_validate_flag'
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display), as it says

> If the string given is a method of the model, ModelAdmin or a callable
>   that returns True or False Django will display a pretty “on” or “off”
>   icon if you give the method a boolean attribute whose value is True.

So, you want

```
def modbus_address_mapping_valid(self,obj):
    try:
        return models.ModbusAddressMapping.objects.filter(object_id=obj.id)[0].valid
    except Exception:
        return False
modbus_address_mapping_valid.short_description = 'Modbus_mapping_validate_flag'
modbus_address_mapping_valid.boolean = True
```

Normally if you want to render certain HTML snippet, like that in your current code, you need `allow_tags` (find it in the same doc, right above the description about `boolean`)

Comment: Yeah,that works well .There is another method using the function _format_html_